# php rename() Device or resource busy

Tags: php, rename

I have code that gives the following error:

> Warning:
>
> [function.rename]: Device or resource busy in

```
if ($handle = opendir($temp_images)) {

        /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
             if ($file == $file) {
             }
             $path = ''; 
             $dir_handle = opendir($path);
             chdir($path);
             $oldfile = $path.$file ;
             $newfile = $path.preg_replace('/[\\&\\%\\$\\ ]+/', '-', $file); // replace &%$ with a - 
    
             if(FALSE == rename($oldfile, $newfile)) 
             {
    
             }

        }

       closedir($handle);
}
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Double check the filenames. It looks like they are not correct.

Comment: filename are in /temp-uploaded/
  its fine

Comment: You have two filenames, both must be fine. You did not reveal their full names, so I can't tell you if they are fine or not. I can only say that this error happens when the file-names are wrong/point to something wrong.

Comment: all filenames are in /home/therealf/public_html/temp-uploaded/
 $oldfile, $newfile filesnames in same directory

Comment: Just add the old and new filename in full to your question. Are you able to perform the rename operation in shell?

Comment: oldfile, newfile  is in same directory .. i not just one file to rename .. i want   how much files in directory thats are rename

Comment: this code rename properly but give this error also  .. how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

if you look at

```
man 2 rename
```

or http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename

you will see

> EBUSY  - The rename fails because oldpath or newpath is a directory that is in use by some process (perhaps as current working
>   directory, or as root directory, or because it was open
>                 for  reading)  or is in use by the system (for example as mount point), while the system considers this an error.  (Note that
>   there is no requirement to return EBUSY in such
>                 cases — there is nothing wrong with doing the rename anyway — but it is allowed to return EBUSY if the system cannot
>   otherwise handle such situations.)

just print output what you are trying to rename and you will see what is happening

Comment: EBUSY is the error returned by rename() syscall, it is then printed by the php interpreter by using someting like the strerror function, which uses the EBUSY errno and turns it into 'device or resource is busy'

Comment: @HAS just print all the variables you are using, esp $oldfile and $newfile, and you will see why the rename() is returning EBUSY.

Comment: what i am trying to say is: just add something like  if ($file != "." || $file != "..") continue; after the while(readdir())

Answer (score 3):

Try to exclude `'.'` and `'..'`.

```
if($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
    continue;
}
```

It works for me. Hopefully, it will work for you. Thanks