# php rename "Device or resource busy in"

Tags: php, resources, rename, device

There is very few information on the Internet on how to solve this problem that I'm having, which is the fact that when i try to rename a file it gives me the error "Device or resource busy in".

this is my code:

```
if ($handler = opendir($thumb_dir)) {
while (false !== ($thumb_name = readdir($handler))) {
$new_thumb_name = str_ireplace("por_eliminar_" . $_POST['id_anuncio'] . "_",$_POST['titulo'] . "_" . $_POST['id_anuncio'] . "_",$thumb_name);
rename($thumb_dir . $thumb_name,$thumb_dir . $new_thumb_name);
}
```

In wamp I didn't got this error, but I'm getting in hostgator... any ideas on what the problem might be ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php rename() Device or resource busy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638587/php-rename-device-or-resource-busy)

Comment: no, it is not a duplicate because it did't solved my problem!