# PHP strtoupper bulk change file names in directory

Tags: php

I'm trying to change all filenames in a directory to uppercase and nothing is happening.  The filenames stay the same.  This includes the filename and extension.  I have error reporting turned on and this is the only warning I get:

> Warning: rename(Parts/.,Parts/.): Device or resource busy in /var/www/site/img/upper.php on line 9
>
> Warning: rename(Parts/..,Parts/..): Device or resource busy in /var/www/site/img/upper.php on line 9

Desired Result Example:  abc.bmp --> ABC.BMP

Code:

```
<?php
 ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1); 
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 $directory="Parts";
 $files = scandir($directory);
 foreach($files as $key=>$name){
    $oldName = $name;
    $newName = strtoupper($name);
    rename("$directory/$oldName","$directory/$newName");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php rename() Device or resource busy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638587/php-rename-device-or-resource-busy)

Comment: @Jessedegans Totally different, I could not derive a solution from your proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to move directory related meta info, do not try moving the `.` or `..` as files.

- The single period `.` means current working directory.
- The double period `..` means parent of the current working directory.

  ```
  $directory = "Parts";
  $files = scandir($directory);
  foreach($files as $name){
      if ($name == '.' || $name == '..') {
         continue;
      }
      $newName = strtoupper($name);
      rename("$directory/$name", "$directory/$newName");
  }
  ```

Comment: That was totally it!  Thanks SO MUCH for the help!

Comment: This is a much better question and answer.  The other is clear as mud.