# php rename - device or resource busy

Tags: php, rename

So I'm trying to move 4 files for a temp upload directory to a folder, but I'm getting a "Device or resource busy" error. Sometimes 4 errors but mostly only 2.
The Files are still being move but my script will not continue after the error.

I tried try/catch and usleep but its not working :(

Any Advice can help :)

Other Posts say that it might be mounted or some special filenames like '.' or '..' but i don't see how this could happen here

```
public function handleFiles($id) {
    $rootdir = '/home/ubuntu/workspace/uploads/';
    $dir = $rootdir . $id . '/';
    $tmpdir = $rootdir . '-1/';
    if (!file_exists($dir) && !is_dir($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir, 0777);
    }
    chmod($dir, 0777);
    if (file_exists($tmpdir) && is_dir($tmpdir)) {
        $tmpfiles = scandir($tmpdir);
        foreach ($tmpfiles as $tmpfile) {
            $oldfile = $tmpdir . $tmpfile;
            $newfile = $dir . $tmpfile;
            rename ($oldfile, $newfile);
        } 
        chmod($dir, 0755);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638587/php-rename-device-or-resource-busy

Comment: Try to exclude '.' and '..' filename in your loop

Comment: _but i don't see how this could happen here_... You're still using `scandir()` without excluding the dot paths.

Comment: in your for each loop just insert this condition if(in_array($tmpfile,array('.','..'))){continue;}

Comment: Thanks Guys - guess i couldn't see the forest because of so may trees ... now it's working